# Why are the number of iterations wrong with this yield generator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iteration, generator, bubble-sort, yield-keyword

So here is a code snippet that I am trying to work with.

```
function* genBubble(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
      yield arr; // returning arr after every iteration
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        swap(arr, j, j + 1); // removed swap for brevity
      }
    }
  }
}
const tempArray = [3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 9, -2];
const genForLoop = genBubble(tempArray);

do {
  console.log(genForLoop.next());
} while (!genForLoop.next().done);
```

This is a simple bubble sort implementation. As you know bubble sort has `n * (n - 1) / 2` iterations, so in this case with array's length being `7`, we have  `7 * (7 - 1) / 2` iterations which is equal to `21`.

But when I run this code, I am only getting `11` iterations. The output is as shown below.

```
{ value: [ 3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 9, -2 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 9, -2 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, -2 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, -2, 9 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 3, 4, 5, 1, 8, -2, 9 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 3, 4, 1, 5, 8, -2, 9 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 3, 4, 1, 5, -2, 8, 9 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 3, 1, 4, 5, -2, 8, 9 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 1, 3, 4, -2, 5, 8, 9 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 1, 3, -2, 4, 5, 8, 9 ], done: false }
{ value: [ 1, -2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9 ], done: false }
```

I am using `node test.js` to run this program(test.js is the file where this program is written in).

Note: I do not want to print the array after each iteration. I want to return it. If that helps.

Comment: Your `do ... while` loop calls the `.next()` function **twice** on each iteration.

Comment: Wow, that is indeed true. How do I call it only once but also check for done?

Comment: `x = genForLoop.next();` inside the loop?

Comment: Store the return value in a variable and then check this variable in the `while` condition. In fact, `.next()`is a **call**, not a value.

Comment: _How do I call it only once but also check for done?_ Remove `do..while` body or just use  empty `while` loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're calling `next` twice, but ignoring the `value` from every other call. Instead, call it **once** and remember the result:

```
let result;
while (!(result = genForLoop.next()).done) {
  console.log(result.value.join(","));
}
```

...or rather more simply, use `for-of` (which means you don't have to have the `genForLoop` identifier):

```
for (const value of genBubble(tempArray)) {
  console.log(value.join(","));
}
```

But (I haven't done a bubble sort in years) I believe your inner loop termination needs to be `j < arr.length - 1`, not just `j < arr.length - i - 1`. I do vaguely recall that the inner loop can be shorter, but not apparently in that way.

Live Example:

```js
function swap(arr, i1, i2) {
  const t = arr[i1];
  arr[i1] = arr[i2];
  arr[i2] = t;
}
function* genBubble(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
      yield arr; // returning arr after every iteration
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        swap(arr, j, j + 1); // removed swap for brevity
      }
    }
  }
}
const tempArray = [3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 9, -2];

for (const value of genBubble(tempArray)) {
  console.log(value.join(","));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Your outer loop condition should be `< arr.length`, not `< arr.length - 1`.

Comment: Thanks, but is `arr.length` really needed? `arr.length - 1` because we do not need to check the last iteration in bubble sort because its already in the right place, right?

Comment: I did hit refresh. I am taking about "Your outer loop condition should be < arr.length, not < arr.length - 1." which you wrote below the code snippet.

Comment: @theprogrammer - Yeah, somehow I messed up the snippet. I've fixed both it and the answer now. I think your *inner* loop termination condition is incorrect, though. Certainly I get an incorrect result with `j < arr.length - i - 1` but a correct result with `j < arr.length - 1`. I haven't done a bubble sort in years, I think there's an opt you can do there, but apparently not quite that one. But the main issue, I believe, wasn't about the bubble sort implementation at all, but how to use a generator.

Comment: Yes, I think there are multiple ways you can write bubble sort by swapping edge cases in outer or inner loops.